# How to pass props during the setup and test phases, without overwriting things?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I've got a test that during it's setup process I pass some default props to the component. Then, in the test, I use `setProps` to pass more specific data into it. Issue is that both default and new data are nested within same props object named `org` and Vue obviously complains that the default is getting overwritten. Is there a way around this?

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "optimisticClearFilters"

Here's an example. When I do this from test, it seems to override all `org` keys.

> wrapper.setProps( { org: { deptSize: [0, 5] }} );

Comment: Please, provide the code of your test and your components (parent and child)

Answer (score 0):

For example if I have:

```js
var posts = {
  status: 6
  rows: [{}, {}, {}]
  details: "some details",
  amount: 1 
}
```

And I want to test component with changed *status* value without exception, I do:

```js
post.status = status
wrapper.setProps({ post: { ...post} })
```